# SQL: simple JOIN gives error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm writing a C# application and am using an Access .mdb. I'm trying to make a simple JOIN of a table with email messages and a table with message relations (each email msg can be assigned to several teams of workers). Unfortunately I'm getting an error with this simple query and can't understand why. Any help appreciated.

```
string queryGetMails = " SELECT * FROM Mails JOIN MailAssignments ON Mails.msgId = MailAssignments.msgId ";
```

And the error I get is:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Comment: You need to qualify the type of join - `JOIN` on its own is not valid syntax for Access. User `INNER JOIN` or `OUTER JOIN` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would specify LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN etc...
Tried your query with Access Interface and doesn't like your syntax without LEFT, INNER, RIGHT before JOIN.

Just as a side note. One of the advantages of using Access is the ease with which you can do tests to correct this kind of errors.

Comment: But this article says INNER JOIN is the same as JOIN so I assumed JOIN is also allowed: [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: I've tried INNER JOIN too but it also gives me an error: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: msgId`. Seems that this is because I'm joining the table on this field (msgId) and so it disappears in the resulting table. But how do I make it stay there?

Comment: I suppose that this is another problem.

Comment: Re your side note: I assume you actually mean, "One of the advantages of using the Access user interface (rather than C# code) to author Access queries is..."

Comment: @onedaywhen Yes, the Access Query Builder is really fast when you need to test or author. Way faster than manually build every query text. However, when possible, I use queries directly saved in the database itself. They are safer because they force you to use the parameters.

Comment: "I use queries directly saved in the database itself" a.k.a. [`PROCEDURES`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-procedure-statement-HP001032219.aspx) and I agree the practice, even though I do not care for the Access UI myself.